# How do I save a music file I got as an email attachment to a folder?

Tags: music

How do I download a youtube music file (sent to me in an email) and save it to the music folder in Ubuntu 18.04?  I have mounted my Windows files and would like to save it to the music folder.

Comment: Did you receive a file attachment, or a link to a web address?

Comment: It was a file attachment.

Comment: @Louii Which application do you use for email? Each will be a little different with its handling of attachments but all will have a 'Save Attachment...' type dialogue...

Comment: I use Gmail as my application.

Comment: @Louii There should be an option in the GMail web interface to download the attachment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/30719